# Avoiding circular dependencies between Maven plugin build and test

Tags: maven

I have a project with the following subprojects:

- foo-codegen

  ...which, as the name implies, performs code generation...
- foo-maven-plugin

  ...which invokes foo-codegen during the build process.

Generally speaking, this works fine. The problem, though, is when I want to test `foo-codegen`: `foo-maven-plugin` isn't yet available during foo-codegen's build cycle if we're putting things together in dependency order, but the build process for the tests invokes that plugin to actually perform the necessary code generation.

What's the right way to break this chain? Should I move foo-codegen's tests into a third subproject? Use the Maven Invoker plugin rather than foo-maven-plugin for doing code generation during the test phase? Something else?

Comment: Why are the tests of foo-codegen using the foo-maven-plugin?

Comment: @Tome The tests of foo-codegen rely on having compiled classes based on generated code available to test. `foo-maven-plugin` is the canonical way to invoke `foo-codegen` during a build process -- using it is both dogfooding and providing an example to end-users (thus, implicit documentation).

Comment: I would personally use basic unit testing on foo-codegen, and more complete (through Maven invoker plugin) end-to-end testing (+ that implicit documentation indeed) inside the foo-maven-plugin. Having to rely on a N-1 version of the codegen for the maven-plugin module sounds too bad for me. What about the release process?

Comment: @Tome ...well, breaking the tests off into their own subproject means no N-1 dependencies, so that _does_ solve things somewhat; it's just that folks working on foo-codegen need to know to run "mvn test" on their whole foo project, not the foo-codegen subproject alone.

Comment: Yes, the other solution would be to create tests that do not need to rely on

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` to a repository on the plugin first, then you can run them any order and do a `mvn compile` separately.

Comment: A `mvn install` can't be done on the plugin unless there exists a version of `foo-codegen` already available to use. More to the point, if the plugin is built against a foo-codegen older than the version under test, it isn't very well testing the code generation when it's used in the test phase of foo-codegen's build.

Comment: you are going to have one or the other have a `bootstrap` version that can get the first build done. Might as well be a `no-op` version of the plugin.

Comment: Hmm -- I asked this poorly. `foo-maven-plugin` is used by Maven during the test phase of `foo-codegen` -- a noop version, by not having any effect, would thus prevent the tests from building. Now, if I can build `foo-maven-plugin` against one version of `foo-codegen,` but then run it a just-built `foo-codegen` jar during the `food-codegen` test phase rather than the one it was compiled against, that would be perfect -- but I don't know whether that's sanely possible, or how it would be implemented.

Comment: compile with the tests disabled, then run the tests separately, use profiles to enable and disable what you need to.

Comment: That's a good approach. I'm not sure if it's lower end-user difficulty/overhead than moving the tests into a separate subproject, though.